# Can't match type Maybe vs not Maybe on Network.URI

Tags: haskell, types, error-handling, type-systems, option-type

Say I want to parse an environment variable, and default to localhost in its absence, using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.3/docs/Network-URI.html

I can write a function like so:

```
parseRabbitURI :: Text -> Maybe URI.URI
parseRabbitURI "" = URI.parseURI "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/"
parseRabbitURI uri = (URI.parseURI . toS) uri
```

This works fine. Now let's say I want to handle errors. I note that parseURI returns a `Maybe` so ostensibly I just need to pattern match on that. So I create a custom Error:

```
data CustomError = MyCustomError Text deriving(Show)
```

I create a helper function:

```
parsedExtractor
  :: MonadError CustomError.MyCustomError m
  => Text
  -> Maybe URI.URI
  -> m(URI.URI)
parsedExtractor originalString Nothing = throwError $ FlockErrors.FailedToParseURI originalString
parsedExtractor _ (Just uri) = do
  pure uri
```

Finally, I modify my initial function:

```
parseRabbitURI :: MonadError CustomError.MyCustomError m => Text -> m(URI.URI)
parseRabbitURI "" = URI.parseURI "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/" >>= parsedExtractor "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/"
parseRabbitURI uri = (URI.parseURI . toS) uri >>= parsedExtractor uri
```

This fails to compile with:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘URI.URI’ with ‘Maybe URI.URI’
  Expected type: URI.URI -> Maybe URI.URI
    Actual type: Maybe URI.URI -> Maybe URI.URI
• In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘parsedExtractor uri’
  In the expression: (URI.parseURI . toS) uri >>= parsedExtractor uri
  In an equation for ‘parseRabbitURI’:
      parseRabbitURI uri
        = (URI.parseURI . toS) uri >>= parsedExtractor uri
```

|
23 | parseRabbitURI uri = (URI.parseURI . toS) uri >>= parsedExtractor uri
   |

And for the life of me I can't figure out why. If the initial implementation returns a Maybe, why is it converting to an unwrapper URI.URI which I can't then pass?

Crucially, when I change the pattern on `parsedExtractor` to expect a string, it *also* fails to compile with the inverse message (

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘URI.URI’
                      with actual type ‘Maybe URI.URI’
```

I feel like I must be missing something completely fundamental. What is going on here?

Comment: I don't think that would be fine either. We can't bind a Maybe x with a function that wants a Maybe x as input - we should just call the function on the Maybe: `parsedExtractor uri . URI.parseURI . toS $ uri`

Comment: apologies that's a syntax error I introduced in my experimentation. I've edited to the correct actual state (Which still errors)

Comment: @amalloy your suggestion worked! If you write it up as an answer (And maybe explain the issue!), I'll be very happy to accept it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And for the life of me I can't figure out why. If the initial
>   implementation returns a Maybe, why is it converting to an unwrapper
>   URI.URI which I can't then pass?

To refer the definition of `>>=` from [Control.Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--62--61-), it has type signture:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Now, compare to the expression:

```
(URI.parseURI . toS) uri >>= parsedExtractor uri
```

We have:

```
m a        ~ (URI.parseURI . toS) uri
(a -> m b) ~ parsedExtractor uri
```

Since `(URI.parseURI . toS) uri` return type `Maybe URI.URI` and `Maybe` is an instance of `Monad`, so

```
m a ~ Maybe URI.URI
```

and

```
(a -> m b) ~ (URI.URI -> m b)
```

and `m b` can be infered to `m (URI.URI)`, so the function (i.e. `parsedExtractor uri`) after `>>=` expected to has type as:

```
(URI.URI -> m (URI.URI))
```

But actual is not.

Comment: Note that the typical notation for type equality uses `~`, not `=`. So I would write, for example, `(URI.parseURI . toS) uri :: Maybe URI.URI ~ m a`.